# warning: declaration of `lr_searchReplace' does not match previous declaration at vuser_init.c (941)

Tags: c, loadrunner, vugen

I am getting the following warning:

> warning: declaration of `lr_searchReplace' does not match previous declaration at vuser_init.c (941)

code is as below:-
**Note:** I have declared `char *abc;` in global.

```
vuser_init()
{
    abc = lr_eval_string("{c_Topic1Name}");
    lr_searchReplace(abc,"c_newtopic1name",'_','-');
    lr_output_message("New string  is :- %s",lr_eval_string("{c_newtopic1name}"));
    return(0);
 }

void lr_searchReplace(char* inputStr, char* outputStr, char lookupChar, char repChar)
{
    char *ptr =inputStr;
    char xchar;
    int len=0;
    int i=0;

    lr_output_message("%s",inputStr);
    xchar = *ptr;//Copy initial
    len=strlen(inputStr);
    while (len>0)
    {
        len--;
        xchar = *ptr;
        if(xchar==lookupChar)
        {
            inputStr[i]= repChar;
        }

        ptr++;
        i++;
   }

   lr_save_string(inputStr,outputStr);
   lr_output_message("%s",inputStr);
}
```

Comment: Declaration should come before usage.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably calling `lr_searchReplace()` before you have provided a declaration of the function. In old versions of the C standard (C89), this was allowed and the function would be given an implicit declaration of:

```
int lr_searchReplace();
```

That is, a function taking an unknown number of non-variadic parameters, and returning `int`. This clearly contradicts the actual declaration which comes later.

In more recent versions of the standard (C99/C11), the compiler is required to produce a diagnostic message if you try to call a function that has not been declared.

You should change your code so that the function definition appears *before* the function call, **or** provide a function declaration *before* the function call. Eg:

```
/* Declaration - Note semi-colon at the end of the declaration */
void lr_searchReplace(char* inputStr, char* outputStr, char lookupChar, char repChar);

/* Function call */
vuser_init()
{
  lr_searchReplace(abc,"c_newtopic1name",'_','-');
}

/* Function definition - including function body */
void lr_searchReplace(char* inputStr, char* outputStr, char lookupChar, char repChar)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

lr_searchReplace(abc,"c_newtopic1name",'_','-');

void lr_searchReplace(char* inputStr, char* outputStr, char lookupChar, char repChar

You are passing a const pointer to outputstr.

Comment: Although a string literal is allowed to reside in read-only memory, its type is array of `char`, _not_ `const char`.